# Show that A4 has no subgroup of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let V= { (1),(12)(34) ,(13)(24),(14)(23) } subgroup .
if H is subgroup such that |H|=6 , HV < A4 is absurde.
Note that V is normal at A4.
Calculating the HV norm, we arrive that is 12, which would imply that HV = A4, I need to find somebody of A4 that is not in HV, but I do not know much about arbitrary order H.

Comment: Didn't you fix $|H| = 6$? Also, please use MathJax to wrap expressions, makes them much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A_4$ has eight 3-cycles, so clearly there is one which is not in H. Can you work out a contradiction to existence of H by looking at its cosets now?